# Convergence of $\sum\frac{\sin n\theta}{n^r}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n \cos (n\theta+a)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, conditional-convergence

Problem 1.

*Show $q$th power of $\sum\frac{\sin n\theta}{n^r}$ (formed by Abel's rule, i.e. $$\nu_n=\sum_{i_1, i_2,\dots,i_q=n} \frac{\sin i_1\theta}{{i_1}^r}\dots\frac{\sin i_q\theta}{{i_q}^r},$$ where $i_j\in\mathbb{Z}_+, r>0, \theta\in\mathbb{R}$) converges when q(1-r)<0.*

(When $q=2$, it is similar to [Show that the series $\frac{1} {\sqrt{1}} -\frac{1} {\sqrt{2}} +\frac{1} {\sqrt{3}} +\dots$ converges, and its square (formed by Abel's rule) doesn't.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3786298/577710). [Show that $\sum\frac{(-1)^{n+1}} {{n}^r} \sum\frac{(-1)^{n+1}} {{n}^s} $ by Abel's rule forms a series that doesn't converge when r+s=1.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3787209/577710))

It seems useful to show that $\sum\frac{\sin n\theta}{n^r}$ converges conditionally.

*Proof:* When $\theta=2k\pi$,  the series converges to $0\sum\frac{1}{n^r}=0$.

When $\delta<\theta<2\pi-\delta$, where $\delta$ >0,
Write $\theta+\pi$ for $\theta$, then $\sum \sin n\theta=\sum (-)^n\sin n\theta$ and so is bounded i.e. $\exists M$, $\forall p, \sum_{n=1}^p (-)^n\sin n\theta <M$ (*Why?*). For $\sum\frac{1}{n^r}$ converges to 0 uniformly w.r.t. $\theta$, according to Hardy's test $\sum\frac{\sin n\theta}{n^r}$ converges.

*Then how does one prove the convergence of the qth power?*

---

Problem 2.

*Show that (1) if $u_n$ is monotonic and $u_n\to0$ as $n\to \infty$, $\delta <\theta<2\pi-\delta$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n \cos (n\theta+a)$ is conditionally convergent; (2) if $u_n$ doesn't vanish and is monotonic, $\theta/2\pi$ is rational, then the sum of the series is oscillatory (fluctuating in neighbourhoods of more than one limit point.); when $\theta/2\pi$ is irrational, the sum takes any value between bounds whose difference is $(\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n)\csc\frac{1}{2}\theta$.*

(2) could be a consequence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos (n\theta+a)$ being oscillatory when $\theta/2\pi\in\mathbb{Q}$. The oscillation is  suggested in [Calculate $\sum_{r=0}^n \cosh(\alpha+2r\beta)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3765005/577710), intuitively, $e^{in\theta}$ is a vector in the real plane , shifting along a chain inscribed in a circle. The chain equals (in the vector addition sense) a smaller vector, which shifts along another chain, which equals a smaller vector. Finally there is a tiny vector shifting along a polygon 'chain', when its 'angle shift' is $2\pi/k$ for some integer k.

If $\theta/2\pi\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$, then similarly the vector vanishes, which however won't orbit a centre along any polygon. Its locus nevertheless becomes smooth and bounded in $\mathbb{C}$, and so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos (n\theta+a)$ varies smoothly and is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$.

*Proof*:

(1)

$\sum \sin n\theta$ is bounded because

$$\sum_{n=1}^p \sin n\theta=\Im (\sum_{n=1}^p e^{ i n\theta})=\Im (e^{i\theta}\frac{ 1-e^{i p\theta}}{1-e^{i \theta}}),$$
which, for $1-e^{i n\theta}=e^{i0}-e^{i n\theta}=e^{i n\theta/2}(e^{-i n\theta/2}-e^{i n\theta/2})= e^{i n\theta/2}\cdot (-2i)\sin(n\theta/2),$  equals
$$\Im (e^{i\theta}\frac{ 1-e^{i p\theta}}{1-e^{i \theta}})
=\Im (e^{i\theta}\frac{e^{i n\theta/2}\cdot (-2i)\sin(n\theta/2)}{e^{i \theta/2}\cdot (-2i)\sin(\theta/2}))
=\Im (\frac{e^{i (n+1)\theta/2}\sin(n\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)})
=\frac{\sin[(n+1)\theta/2]\sin(n\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)},$$ bounded by $_-^+$ $\frac{1}{\sin(\theta/2)}.$ (*The idea is from an answer.*)

$\forall\ p, \sum_{n=1}^p \cos (n\theta+a)$ is bounded by $M$ (independent of p) (consider $\Im(\sum_{n=1}^p e^{i(n\theta+a)})$). Acoording to Hardy's test, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n \cos (n\theta+a)$ converges uniformly.

(2)

When $\theta/2\pi\in \mathbb{Q}$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(n\theta+a)$ oscillates among a finite set $H_c$ because:

$\exists$ p, q coprime, such that $\theta=2\pi\frac{p}{q}$ (it suffices to discuss the case when p is odd, i.e. p, 2q coprime), and so
$$\sum_{n=1}^m e^{i (n\theta+a)}=\frac{e^{i [\frac{(m+1)\theta}{2}+a]}\sin(m\theta/2)}{\sin(\theta/2)}
= \frac{\sin(m\frac{2\pi p}{2q})}{\sin(\theta/2)}e^{i (\frac{2\pi (m+1)p}{2q}+a)}
= \frac{\sin(2\pi\frac{mp(\mod 2q)}{2q})}{\sin(\theta/2)}e^{i (2\pi\frac{(m+1)p(\mod 2q)}{2q}+a)},$$
that is, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{i (n\theta+a)}$ oscillates among a finite set $H=\{\frac{\sin(2\pi\frac{1-p}{2q})}{\sin(\theta/2)}e^{i (2\pi\frac{1}{2q}+a)},\frac{\sin(2\pi\frac{2-p}{2q})}{\sin(\theta/2)}e^{i (2\pi\frac{2}{2q}+a)},\dots,\frac{\sin(2\pi\frac{2q-1-p}{2q})}{\sin(\theta/2)}e^{i (2\pi\frac{2q-1}{2q}+a)}\}.$

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n\cos(n\theta+a)$ is oscillatory because:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=l$ exists, for $u_n$ is decreasing and lower bounded; and
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n\cos(n\theta+a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (u_n-l)\cos(n\theta+a)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty l\cos(n\theta+a),$$ where, for $u_n-l\to 0$ steadily, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (u_n-l)\cos(n\theta+a)$ converges uniformly to $f(\theta),$ and where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty l\cos(n\theta+a)$ oscillates among $lH_c$; and so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n\cos(n\theta+a)$ oscillates among $f(\theta)+lH_c.$

*How does one prove the case when $\theta/2\pi\in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$?* Possibly one needs to calculate the bounds $B_1, B_2$ of limit of the series, and then show that the map $f:m\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^m u_n\cos(n\theta+a), \mathbb{N_+}\to[B_1, B_2]$ is onto.

Comment: Why does the proof "seem" to be like that?  The series as written converges by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).  The title here asks about conditional convergence.  Uniform convergence is another matter.

Comment: Because a similar example in my textbook does that.

Comment: Well, it's a text not in English. But I can describe the example: prove the uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin n\theta/n$ in the range $\delta\leq\theta\leq2\theta-\delta$ and the proof given is replacing $\theta$ by $\theta+\pi$.

Comment: Now that you've changed the question it is not clear what you mean by q-th power converging.  Is q a fixed integer? Can you clearly write the series for which uniform convergence is in question?

Comment: q can be any positive integer as long as q(1-r)<1.

Answer (score 2):

The question seems to be is $\sum_{n=1}^m (-1)^n \sin n \theta$ bounded for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$?

Note that

$$\sum_{n=1}^m (-1)^n \sin n \theta = \sum_{n=1}^m \cos n\pi \sin n \theta = \sum_{n=1}^m \sin n (\theta+ \pi), $$

and use the well-known result

$$\sum_{n=1}^m \sin nx = \frac{\sin \frac{mx}{2}\sin \frac{(m+1)x}{2}}{\sin \frac{x}{2}}$$

Thus, for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^m (-1)^n \sin n \theta \right| = \frac{\left|\sin \frac{m(\theta+\pi)}{2}\right|\, \left|\sin \frac{(m+1)(\theta+\pi)}{2}\right|}{\left|\sin \frac{\theta + \pi}{2}\right|} \leqslant \frac{1}{\left|\sin \frac{\theta + \pi}{2}\right|}$$

Comment: The formula is very nice. But unfortunately I don't know it. Would you like to show me where I can find a proof of it? Or I will try to prove it myself.

Comment: Aren't finite sums always bounded?

Comment: @Morph:  OP wants to know if this sum is bounded for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$ or uniformly bounded for all $m$ and $\theta$ in some interval.

Comment: @CharlieChang: See my derivation (without $x$) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1543898/148510)

Comment: I see. By multipiying the sum with a constant we can change it to something like telescopic series.

Comment: Yes. Or as you suggested do the geometric sum with $e^{in\theta}$ and take the imaginary part.